# If you know 2 of 8 questions but the test has only 4 questions. What is the probability you will know at least one of the questions on the test?

Tags: probability

**Background:**

This is a **hypothetical** question that and my friend and I have been arguing over all day. We're both upper-year mathematics students and should reasonably be able to come up with the solution, however, we've been arguing about it non stop.

**Situation:**

There's a test bank with $8$ questions in it. The test will randomly give you $4$ of these questions. If you happen to know $2$ of the $8$ questions ahead of time,

**A)** What is the probability your test would have at least one of the questions you know?
**B)** What is the probability your test would have both of the questions you know?

So far we've come up with the solutions for part **A)** of:

- simply $25\%$ because you know $25$ percent of the questions
- $39 \%$ because you have a $\frac{2}{8}$ chance of knowing the first question and a $\frac{1}{7}$ of the second and $\frac{2}{8}+ \frac{1}{7} \approx 0.39$
- $\frac{1}{16}$ because the test has $\frac{1}{2}$ of the total questions and you have a $\frac{1}{8}$ chance of getting your question
- $\frac{1}{8}$ similarly, because you know two of the questions so $2 \times \frac{1}{16}= \frac{1}{8}$

For part **B)**, we think it could be

- $\frac{2}{8} \times \frac{1}{7} \approx 3\% $
- $\frac{1}{16}$?

We're really lost and at this point, I think we need a third party to arbitrate our discussion haha.

Comment: For part B), the probability should be $$\frac{\text{ways to choose 4 questions from 8 but 2 of them are fixed}}{\text{ways to choose 4 questions from 8}} = \frac{6\choose2}{8\choose4}$$. Similarly for part A).

Comment: Thanks for your Solution on part B. That makes perfect sense now! I'm still confused about how it relates to part A. In my mind (could be wrong) it seems that since you need only one of two questions to meet the criteria, you would need some form of addition in the probability. Still thinking on this one, but thanks for the solution on the first part!

Comment: For Part A, you are right that it requires some addition of probability. Knowing at least one question implies that either both of them are known, or only one of them are known. And we have already found the probability of the former case. How about the latter case? It should be $$\frac{2 \cdot {6\choose3}}{8\choose4}$$. The sum of two probability will be the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd like to offer an alternative approach. I will instead find the probability that neither of the two questions you know is selected, then subtract that from 1. There are $6\choose 4$ ways to pick a set of 4 questions from the 6 questions you don't know, and there are $8\choose 4$ ways to pick a set of 4 questions without restrictions. So, the probability that you know none of the 4 questions is
$$\frac{6\choose 4}{8\choose 4}=\frac{3}{14}\approx 21.43\%$$
Subtracting this from 1 gives a probability of $\frac{11}{14}$ of knowing at least 1 question on the test, or about a $78.57\%$ chance.

I checked this with [python](https://onlinegdb.com/HyEpllVgv), and it numerically lines up.

Comment: Dang, this will absolutely end the rivalry, thank you very much. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: It should be 78.57, I think.

Comment: No problem @EthanPullan, glad to help! Also thanks for catching that richrow, I'll fix it right away.